# How to secure GIT Repository Options in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs-security

We're setting up a new on prem TFS 2017 and would like to secure who can change options on a repository.  [image: Example of Repository options]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE2:**

@AllanPalmer I help you submit the [user voice here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/20382010-restrict-user-secure-for-git-repository-options-in), please track it as needed.

---

**UPDATE1:**

There isn't the secure setting to restrict access the "Options"

You can only set the **existing** User/Group permissions for specific repository based on your requirements.

You can follow below ways to set the repo permission:

- Go to Code **>** Manage Repositories **>** Select the specific
  repository **>** Select the User/Group **>** Set the permissions
  based on your requirements (eg set **Manage permissions** to
  **Deny**)

**or**

- Navigate to the specific repository, Right click the repository **>**
  Security **>** Select the User/Group to set the permission
  accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you for your response.  We did this today, and we were able to set our test user as you illustrated above, but we were still able to manage the options on the specific repository:

Comment: @AllanPalmer Which options do you want to be restricted? What's the "options" exactly mean? What's your real  requirements? The Repository level permissions are all here, you can set  them based on your requirements. "Manage permissions" just an example for your reference.

Comment: @AllanPalmer Is the user in Project Collection Administrators group?

Comment: @Andy-MSFT Please see the screen shot that I attached to question.  We would only like the administrators to be able to change those options.

Comment: @AllanPalmer Unfortunately, there is no the settings to restrict that, if you want this feature, you can suggest here with the user voice https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services

Comment: @AllanPalmer I help you submit the [user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/20382010-restrict-user-secure-for-git-repository-options-in) here, please track it as needed.